# Copy complete VPS using rsync

Tags: vps, rsync

I'm having a hard thought about copying my VPS. By advice, I got to rsync and now I would like to use it for copying my websites which are hosted on my VPS.

The situation is this; 
I've got a VPS with a directadmin license on a monthly basis, and I want to copy all the website data of this VPS to my new one with a lifetime license. I've installed CentOS7 on the new one, including all the firewall stuff. So it should just copy the databases etc from my existing users.

I definitely don't want a 1:1 copy of the complete VPS, there is some odd software on the first one, which I want to get rid of.

After I've transferred all the website data, I want to make sure both VPS's have the same data, so I can split the incoming traffic.

A lot of questions here :-) 
- what is the right directory for all the website data including the databases? 
- how do is set up a synchronizing workflow between both VPS?

Answer (score 2):

Copying files versus DB are 2 different things.

You may copy your website files anytime without shutting down any service.  But that won't work nicely for MySQL.

In order to rsync MySQL, you'll first need to stop the service on both servers (origin and target).

From what I understood, you'll need to make a choice regarding your MySQL server configuration.  Either setup a Multi-Master-MySQL cluster or use a single MySQL node (I would suggest the later one, the single MySQL node, since it is much easier to manage).

The MySQL server may be hosted on one of your VPS or on a dedicated one.

In order to configure your web app to talk with MySQL, simply change "localhost" (or 127.0.0.1 if that is the case) to the MySQL server IP (it could be a local or public IP).  You'll also want to make sure to allow both server IP/hostname to accept incoming queries on your MySQL.

Regarding the website files;
rsync is fine in order to clone your website from a server to the other.  But it will consume too much IO if you plan to use it as a synchronizing solution.



What you could do would be (easiest (1) and a more complex(2) design):

1a) create a NFS on one of your 2 nodes (probably your "master" node)
1b) mount the dynamic directories on the second server (i.e. For wordPress, that would probably be your uploads directory)
1c) for any update, you will need to figure out a solution such as rsync or, even better, a code repo such as git

2a) setup a network file system such as GlusterFS or Ceph which would be using your web app doc root directory as a mount point.
2b) mount your directories on both servers

Something else which wasn't asked but that you'll want to make sure to cover is the SSL configuration;
Usually the load balancer is also doing the SSL offload and traffic between the load balancer and the slaves is unencrypted.  So you'll probably want to declare to your slaves that the traffic originating from the load balancer should be interpreted as "secured" and using SSL when requested (so your website will return https:// URLs even if it is processed on non-https port).

Whit that said, this isn't an easy setup and configuration since you'll need to cover all the bases with your clients (i.e. if they change the PHP configuration, you'll need to make sure that the new configuration will also be taken in account on the second node).